# ¿Como mostrar registros duplicados MySQL y PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

¿Como puedo obtener registros duplicados de un producto?
Estoy desarrollando un sitio para vender videojuegos en linea, cuento con una barra de busqueda para que muestre los titulos ingresando su SKU, pero quiero hacer que muestre los juegos que tengan su duplicado. Por ejemplo:

```
===================================================================
|| SEQJ || Nombre_Juego || Categoria_Juego  || Cant_Disp ||  SKU ||
||=================================================================
|| 001  || gears_of_war || accion_disparos  ||    10     || 0123 ||
|| 001  || gears_of_war || accion_disparos  ||    20     || 0124 ||
|| 001  || gears_of_war || accion_disparos  ||    20     || 0125 ||
|| 002  || metal_gear_5 || sigilo_accion_a  ||    20     || 0126 ||
|| 002  || metal_gear_5 || sigilo_accion_a  ||    20     || 0127 ||
|| 002  || metal_gear_5 || sigilo_accion_a  ||    20     || 0128 ||
|| 003  || god_of_war_1 || accion_3_persona ||     5     || 0129 ||
|| 003  || god_of_war_1 || accion_3_persona ||    30     || 0131 ||
|| 003  || god_of_war_1 || accion_3_persona ||    30     || 0132 ||
|| 005  || pro_evo_socc ||     deportes     ||     2     || 0134 ||
==================================================================
```

Lo que necesio es que al buscar por el SKU del producto me traiga todos los productos(por ejemplo, todos los gears of war) y no solo el ultimo valor(en el ejemplo de gears_of_war con SKU 0125, sino todos los gears_of_war)

Nota: Hay repetidos, pero necesito que me traiga esos repetidos(cuando sea el caso).
Saludos.

Comment: ¿Los repetidos se consiguen de acuerdo al valor de la columna `SEQJ`, cierto?

Comment: Así es, los SEQJ se pueden repetir...bueno; en la tabla tengo un id autoincrementable que no cambia, pero en efecto el SEQJ es con el que quiero conseguir los duplicados.

Answer (score 2):

Podrías ejecutar un query como sigue:

```
/*
    query para obtener los elementos de tu tabla (no sé el nombre)
    basados en el valor de SEQJ
    el cual lo obtendremos de la misma tabla pero mediante un subquery
*/
SELECT t2.SEQJ,
  t2.Nombre_Juego,
  t2.Categoria_Juego,
  t2.Cant_Disp,
  t2.SKU
FROM tabla t2
WHERE t2.SEQJ = (
    /*
        subquery para obtener el SEQJ que indica los juegos
        colocamos LIMIT 1 para que siempre devuelva 1 resultado
    */
    SELECT t1.SEQJ
    FROM tabla t1
    WHERE t1.SKU = :sku //aquí iría el valor del SKU que buscas
    LIMIT 1)
```

Comment: la tabla es "vgames"

Comment: Bueno, cambia `tabla` por `vgames` y listo.

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda, me funcionó!
Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Asumiendo que el campo `SKU` no tiene valores repetidos en la tabla, con un simple join a la misma tabla se puede lograr:

```
select t2.*
  from vgames t1
  join vgames t2
    on t2.seqj = t1.seqj
 where t1.sku = '0125'
 order by t2.sku
```

Nota que le puse un `ORDER BY` para que los resultados te salgan en orden de `SKU`. Puedes modificarlo para obtener los registros en el orden que quieres. Solo asegúrate de usar una campo de `t2`, no `t1`. O, si el orden no te importa, puedes quitar la claúsula `ORDER BY` simplemente.

Comment: Gracias por el consejo, me sirvió en el problema que tenía.